# Formula for ratio test and determining convergence

Tags: convergence-divergence, power-series

In my recent lecture, I was told that the ratio test was R was equal to the limit as "n" approaches infinity, of the absolute of $(An)/(An+1)$ where n/n+1 are subscripts. Googling the ratio test, everywhere shows that it's the reverse with (An+1) being on top. Are they interchangeable? Thank you and sorry for the lack of formatting. I'm still trying to get used to it.

Comment: It's less natural to have $A_{n+1}$ in the denominator. If you do, then the ratio test becomes $\limsup_n \lvert a_{n}/a_{n+1} \rvert>1$ implies convergence and $<1$ implies divergence the sum is infinite. The reason why this is a less natural way to state the test is because the point of the test is to compare the series with a geometric series.

Answer (score 1):

As Andrew said, you want the later term in the numerator. Sure, it works out still, but the point is to have the ratio test act as a special comparison test.

Recall the (direct) comparison test: Suppose $a_n \leq b_n$ for each $n$. If $\sum b_n < \infty,$ then $\sum a_n < \infty.$ The point of having the later term in the numerator is to force it to behave like a convergent geometric series.

We know $\sum kr^n$ converges when $|r| < 1.$ Let $\rho = \displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty} \left| \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \right|.$ When $\rho < 1,$ the ratio test says the sum $\sum a_n$ is convergent. Why? Well,

$$ \sum a_n < \sum a_{n-1} \rho ^n < \infty $$

and you've got the result. While there is no penalty for phrasing the ratio test with the later term in the denominator, it loses the natural use as a special comparison test.